# get a string value from EditText within if statement

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext

I want to do the following: when a **CheckBox** is checked a **TextView** appears then the user can put whatever he needs, but the problem is I can't get the text written in the **EditText** to put it in a **String** variable, because it takes the initial value which is "nothing" when it enters the if statement. Any help?

i am new at this website , here is the part of the code i am talking about

```
   SendSMS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true) {
                sendText.setVisibility(0);
                smstext = sendText.getText().toString();
            } else if (isChecked == false) {
                sendText.setVisibility(8);
                smstext = "";
            }

        }
    });
```

here.. after checking the sendsms to true edittext (sendText) will appear

.
.
.
.
.
.

here when the user enter any text i need to put it into a string (sms) to be stored in the data base ,, sorry for the mistakes

```
    break;
    case R.id.SaveImage:
        String x = EventName.getText().toString();
        if (x.contentEquals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a Title",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Swipe.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String typename = type;
            String name = EventName.getText().toString();
            String location = EventLocation.getText().toString();
            String dateFrom = DateFrom.getText().toString();
            String dateTo = EbDate.getText().toString();
            String timeFrom = mPickTime.getText().toString();
            String timeTo = EbTime.getText().toString();
            String duration = durationresult.getText().toString();
            String alarm = alarmresult.getText().toString();
            String repeat = repeatresult.getText().toString();
            String audios = Audios;
            String sms = smstext;
            String call = calltext;
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert(name, location, dateFrom, dateTo,
                    timeFrom, timeTo, duration, alarm, repeat, typename,
                    audios, sms, call);

            updateList();
            // reset form
            EventName.setText(null);
            EventLocation.setText(null);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? please post some code to help others which like to help you

Comment: If you don't post a code we can only reply with an algorithm which won't help you much..

Comment: i have tuns of code so i entered the part i am talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the only time you are setting smstext is when the value of the checkbox changes.  The user can only enter text into that textbox when it is visible, so when the value of the checkbox changes, logically the textbox is empty and smstext will always be null.

Have you tried something like this:

```
case R.id.SaveImage:
        ...
        String sms = sendText.getText().toString();
        ...
```